# Unknown attribute error after renaming a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I have three user roles:

```
  enum role: { staff: 0, clinician: 1, admin: 2 }
```

I had a user_id column in my patients table to store the id of the staff user who created the patient record. To improve the clarity of the name, I renamed the column from user_id to author_id and adjusted the relationship best I knew how to reference the change to the foreign key.

When I try to access /patients/new, I get the error:

```
unknown attribute 'user_id' for Patient.
```

The error specifically highlights this line in my new patients method:

```
@patient = current_user.patients.build
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks for any help!

**patients table:**

```
 create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
        t.integer  "age"
        t.integer  "staff_clinician_id"
        t.integer  "author_id"
        t.index ["author_id"], name: "index_patients_on_author_id"
        t.index ["staff_clinician_id"], name: "index_patients_on_staff_clinician_id"
      end
```

**Patient Model**

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, -> { where role: :staff }, foreign_key: 'author_id'
```

**Staff User concern**

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module StaffUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :university
    has_many :patients
    has_many :referral_requests
    validates :university_id, presence: true, if: :staff?
  end

  class_methods do
  end
end
```

**Here is my patients controller:**

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :require_login

def new
    @patient = current_user.patients.build
end

def index
    authorize Patient
    @patients = policy_scope(Patient)
end

def show
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @patients = Patient.all
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    if @patient.update_attributes(patient_params)
        flash[:success] = "Patient Updated!"
        render 'patients/index'
    else
        render "edit"
    end
end


def create
    @patient = current_user.patients.build(patient_params)
    if @patient.save
        flash[:success] = "Patient Created!"
        redirect_to new_referral_request_path(patient_id: @patient.id)
    else
        Rails.logger.info(@patient.errors.inspect)
        render 'patients/new'
end
end


private

def patient_params
    params.require(:patient).permit(:age, :staff_clinician_id, :author_id, insurance_ids: [], gender_ids: [], concern_ids: [], race_ids: [])

end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have a User model with `has_many :patients` (I assume that's where you used your StaffUser concern). Rails infers that the foreign key on the association table is `user_id`. You need to change this to:

```
##user.rb
has_many :patients, foreign_key: "author_id"
```